# How to authorize to my app using my frontend for Google Login instead keycloak UI

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, google-authentication

I want to secure my spring boot app I added authorization using keycloak adapter, right now I want to add google auth authorization, I did it using this tutorial https://keycloakthemes.com/blog/how-to-setup-sign-in-with-google-using-keycloak.
The google auth was added, but in keycloak UI only, I want to see the Google Login button in my fronted, instead keycloak page, how to do it? Any help will be very helpfull (tutorial, documentation).

Comment: I almost did it but I get another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696020/keycloak-social-login-rest-api-redirected-you-too-many-times